# How to refresh the Telerik RadGrid control using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

How to refresh the Telerik RadGrid control using JavaScript?

Answer (score 14):

from telerik documentation:

```
function RefreshGrid()
{
  var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
  masterTable.rebind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using client binding for the grid - check out [this help document](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/client-side-binding-specifics.html).